# How can i get a reference of a Fragment (SupportMapFragment) loaded by the NavHostFragment (of the Navigation Architecture components)

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I was trying out the Navigation Architecture Components introduced in the google IO 2018 conference.
I'm trying to make an app with three tabs, one fragment for every tab.
In one of them i would like to put a map using the Google Maps API.
Normally you should do this in the OnCreate of the Activity

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

`R.id.map is` the id of the `SupportMapFragment` inside `main_activity.xml`

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

However the Navigation Architecture components setup is a little different.
`main_activity.xml` contains only a `NavHostFragment` (where every screen's fragment is loaded) and a `BottomNavigationView` to go between the different destinations of the app.

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >

</fragment>


<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My navigation graph looks like this

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
app:startDestination="@id/map">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/endFragment"
    android:name="douglas.leone.easytaxi.EndFragment"
    android:label="fragment_end"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_end" />

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/startFragment"
    android:name="douglas.leone.easytaxi.StartFragment"
    android:label="fragment_start"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_start" />

</navigation>
```

As you can see there are two fragments `startFragment` and `endFragment` for the first and third tab. In the second one there is the `SupportMapFragment` that i'm trying to reference.
I cannot use the standard `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(int id)` way because `main_activity.xml` contains only a `NavHostFragment`

I tried experimenting with `getChildFragmentManager()` without much success.
I also tried `navController.getCurrentDestination()` but it returns a `NavDestination` object that i cannot use to retrieve the loaded fragment.

The only solution that i found is to add the `SupportMapFragment` directly in `activity_main.xml` making it completely separate from the navigation graph, but it's more a workaround than a solution because I have to manually deal with showing and hiding the map when the user it's in another screen.

If anybody knows a proper solution please share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the `SupportMapFragment` directly to your navigation graph, you should add your own Fragment class that will own and manage the `SupportMapFragment` - it would be the one to call `getMapAsync` and have the `SupportMapFragment` in its own layout.

The goal of Navigation is to decouple the Activity from the contents of the individual destinations. Having the Activity manage a single destination is not a recommended pattern.

Comment: It's the first thing i tried but i still wasn't able to reference it because `getFragmentmanager().findFrgmentById()` isn't able to find it. I can only get a reference of the `View` object using `findViewById()`

Comment: I was able to find a solution calling `getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById()` directly in the Fragment's `onViewCreated`

Comment: Is it possible to use the map fragment without the support lib, e.g. with AndroidX?

Comment: @BenoitDuffez - if you've used the Refactor to AndroidX option, then you should be able to use SupportMapFragment with AndroidX

Comment: @ianhanniballake: does that involve the jetifier? Because both `MapFragment` and `SupportMapFragment` subclass classes outside of the AndroidX scope.

Comment: @BenoitDuffez - framework Fragments are deprecated, so you shouldn't use anything that subclasses them, such as MapFragment. Jetifier was specifically built so that you could use classes like SupportMapFragment in AndroidX projects

Comment: Then I'm confused (and maybe should I ask my own question): how can we add the map fragment to the view hierarchy since AndroidX fragment managers don't accept neither legacy android.app fragment nor legacy support fragments?

Comment: @BenoitDuffez - all legacy Support Library fragments are transformed via jetifier into AndroidX fragments. If that's not what you're seeing, you should create a bug for the AndroidX team.

Comment: It is, but I don't understand how (I've read through bytecode swaps) and when (compile time? which compiler (java/kotlin)? a gradle plugin? at runtime?). For example I made my map fragment work as expected, but there's a compiler warning about a cast that can never succeed on `childFragmentManager.findFragmentById` to `SupportMapFragment` (the compiler expects AndroidX), yet it totally works at runtime. Is that the intended behavior? (I mean the IDE warning)

Comment: @BenoitDuffez - there should be no IDE warnings, no